# turtle graphics goto() not working correctly

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

there are two paddles and a ball in a pong game the ball doesn't go back to 0, 0 after hitting right border in this game the whole script isnt finished yet only a bit I assume it has something to do with the goto() command but i do not know as i am new to python please help me figure this out here is the script of the game:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.title('Pong by me')
wn.bgcolor('black')
wn.setup(width=800, height=600)
wn.tracer(0)

# Paddle A
paddle_a = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_a.speed(0)
paddle_a.shape('square')
paddle_a.color('white')
paddle_a.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_a.penup()
paddle_a.goto(-350, 0)

# Paddle B
paddle_b = turtle.Turtle()
paddle_b.speed(0)
paddle_b.shape('square')
paddle_b.color('white')
paddle_b.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
paddle_b.penup()
paddle_b.goto(350, 0)

# Ball
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
ball.shape('square')
ball.color('white')
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = -2

# Function
def paddle_a_up():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y +=20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_a_down():
    y = paddle_a.ycor()
    y -=20
    paddle_a.sety(y)

def paddle_b_up():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y +=20
    paddle_b.sety(y)

def paddle_b_down():
    y = paddle_b.ycor()
    y -=20
    paddle_b.sety(y)

# keyboard binding
wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_up, 'w')
wn.onkeypress(paddle_a_down, 's')
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, 'Up')
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_down, 'Down')

# Main game loop
while True:
    wn.update()

    # Move the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # Border checking
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 390:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx += -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your border checking should look like this

```
    # Border checking
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 390:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if ball.xcor() < -390:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1
```

Then it works as expected

Comment: It still dosent work for me it might be that i have an old, slow laptop but the ball just appears to go off the side still

Comment: Im using python 3.8 if that makes a difference

Comment: Me too, could you post a gif of what happens on your machine and a description of how it is different from what you want to achieve?

Comment: Im not currently near my laptop when i get a chance i will send a video

Comment: what im trying to acheive is for the ball to teleport back to the middle and move in the opposite direction when the x coordinate goes past -390 and 390 but what happens instead is that the ball goes off the screen and dosent come back

Comment: It says that the problem is in the line:

Comment: Ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)